# Cylindrical polar coordinates-Surface/Flux integral

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am given that the vector $\mathbf{u} =  2z^{3}re_{r} +  3z^{2}r^{2}e_{z}$ in the cylindrical polar coordinates.

I am required to find the surface integral but instead of using the Gauss theorem I wanted to do it directly.

$\int_{a}^{b}u. \,dA $

What is $dA$ equal to?

Comment: You have not mentioned the surface for the integral.

Comment: I am given that g = $z^{3}(x^{2}+y^{2})$. $\mathbf{u}$ is the grad of $\mathbf{g}$ and i need to find the surface integral of the $\mathbf{u}$ for the axis that runs from z=-1 to z=1.